# Simple Tabs with CSS and jQuery - Customizing & Duplicating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a website, using about 5 'J.Query-Tabbed-Window Boxs' via this Open Source Script; **'http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tabs-w-css-jquery/#comment-16690'** it implements great, and have got it working and holds up pretty well in even IE 6 +

I'm having some trouble using this for the four more times on the same page, I've duplicated the mark-up, even tried duplicating the styles and renaming the mark-ups Divs and related styles - but still unsuccessful. I shouldn't have to touch the classes, right? The tabs render and are fine, but no matter what I've tried so far, the tabs, when clicked - do nothing within that window/area, but instead link to the navigation within the initial first 'tabbed box'.

Any suggestions on implementing this 4 more times, on the same page?

The Code I have implemented for this is exactly the same as displayed in the reference link; Here is a link of it implemented in 1 instance. **"http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/tabs/"**

The HTML Mark-Up I'm using can be viewed in full here; '**http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08860571195966022003&gk=transfer**' via tinyupload within a text .rtf file.

cheers for the help!

Comment: Can you provide a link or a fiddle or some code?  It is hard to give insight without seeing any code or a visual.

Comment: That's understandable - I can't post the link of what I have implemented - but as far as the issue, I'm using the same mark-up, css, and code as the additional Link I've posted of the tabbed box used in one instance. I'm using that exactly, just trying to have it appear in 4 different areas on one long vertical page, I've been trying to duplicate it, & have not altered any orginal code or implemented any content. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the javascript referenced in the link above does not take into account any grouping for the tabs. In order to have multiple tabs on the same page, you must add some grouping logic to the javascript.

You should probably also group your html. EX:

```
<div class="tab-parent">
    <ul class="tabs">...</ul>
    <div class="tab_container">...</div>
</div>
```

I have thrown together a quick DIRTY example of how you would accomplish this at http://jsfiddle.net/justinobney/aSQjF/2/

[Fullscreen Example](http://jsfiddle.net/justinobney/aSQjF/2/show)

You should probably refactor it though...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found that taking another look at the mark-up helped, as I responded to atif089 above, I now have the functionality of the additional tabs working - but, am now just having problems seeing the initial box/area within on the initial page load. Only the tabs are present initially, after one is clicked, the content and everything starts to work. It seems I am getting close - are you sure it'd be necessary to incorporate 'grouping logic'? I appreciate the example - but how could I insert that snippet of code into what I'm working with?

Comment: $(".tab_content:first").show(); is only going to show the FIRST div.tab_content of all 4 boxes.. thus the need to call it on each parent.. EX: PARENT.find(".tab_content:first").show();

Comment: Thanks again Justin - I tried inserting the sample script you provided with your reference link and it didn't seem to work. It did, however, change the transitions to a lot slower when a tab is clicked. Dumb question, but how can I implement it to work correctly? All I need to do from here, it seems, is to get the initial tab to show upon page load within all 'tab boxs' and possibly not have the other menus content-view disappear upon clicking another window/areas tab. Possibly the solution should fix both?

Comment: A link to the work or the full html would be needed... Feel free to email me.

Comment: Justin - That'd be awesome. Here's a link via 'TinyUpload' with all the HTML Mark-Up I'm using. http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08860571195966022003&gk=transfer  It's saved in text file. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thats perhaps because you are using same ID for all tab groups like tab1, tab2 all the time.

use a unique identifier for each tab, and make sure links are pointed to each tab properly like  this

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Submit</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
        <!--Content-->
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
       <!--Content-->
    </div>
</div>


<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab3">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Submit</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
        <!--Content-->
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
       <!--Content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried this. ..And just took another look at it and by doing so, now, after clicking one of the tabs, the area/box within, begins to function and pull in the content correctly. But, on initial page load - there are still just 'tabs' present, without the initial box underneath as there's supposed to be and is there is with the first instance of the 'Tabbed area'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="tabcontainer">

  <ul class="tabheading">

                    <li class="active" rel="tab1"><a href="javascript:return false;">Tab 1</a> </li>

                    <li rel="tab2"><a href="javascript:return false;">Tab 2</a> </li>
 </ul>



  <div class="tabbody active" id="tab1" style="display: block;">
    Tab 1
    Your Text or html

  </div>

  <div class="tabbody" id="tab2" style="display: none;">
    Tab 2
    Your Text or html

  </div>

</div>


<script>
     $('.tabheading li').click(function () {
            var tabid = $(this).attr("rel");
            $(this).parents('.tabcontainer').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.tabbody').hide();
            $('#' + tabid).show();
            $(this).addClass('active');

            return false;
        });
    </script>
```